# Hbase multiple partial rowkeys scan

Tags: hbase, nosql

I am trying find a solution to scan a Hbase table, with multiple partial keys from the same rowkey.

example:

```
RowKey: account_id|name|age|transaction_date
             12345|abc |50 |2016-05-05 08:10:10
```

Here I want to scan a hbase table to get all the possible values with the following partial key combination:

```
Rowkey: account_id|transation_date
             12345|2016-05-05 08:10:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [prefix filter.](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/PrefixFilter.html)... some thing like below.

#### prefixfilter:

> This filter takes one argument  a prefix of a row key. It returns only
> those key-values present in a row that starts with the specified row
> prefix
>
> Syntax
>
> `PrefixFilter (<row_prefix>)`

Same can be used with java client as well

```
scan 'yourtable', {FILTER => "PrefixFilter('12345|abc|50|2016-05-05')"}

scan 'yourtable', {STARTROW=>'12345' FILTER => "PrefixFilter('2016-05-05 08:10:10')"}
OR 
scan 'yourtable', {ENDROW='2016-05-05 08:10:10'"}
```

based on your requirement...

NOTE : java hbase scan api also has same methods if you want to do it from java

Comment: If you are running the scan from code. The best performance is to create multiple scan with STARTROW/ENDROW and union the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RowFilter with regexstring.

```
scan ‘myTable’, {FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:12345.*2016-05-05 08:10:10’)”}
```